# In WordPress, how to modify the Set-Cookie header value to include SameSite=None to it?

Tags: wordpress

I am using react for frontend and WordPress for backend. The frontend and backend are hosted with different domain name. The Set-Cookie that is being received by the frontend is not setting the cookie because it does not have SameSite=None. For this reason, I want to add SameSite=None to the value of Set-Cookie header.

How can I add the SameSite=None for every Set-Cookie header to the response in WordPress?